# Слушатель для переменной

Tags: android, listener

Нашел в сети следующий [пример](http://javatalks.ru/topics/25270)
 Слушаемый класс:

```
class ListenToMe {     
            private String variable = "Initial";
            private PropertyChangeSupport support = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);     
            public void addListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
                support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
            }     
            public void removeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
                support.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
            }

            public void setVariable(String newValue) {
                String oldValue = variable;
                variable = newValue;
                support.firePropertyChange("variable", oldValue, newValue);
            }
}
```

Слушатель:

```
class MyListener implements PropertyChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Property \"" + event.getPropertyName() + "\" has new value: " + event.getNewValue());
        }
    }
```

в слушатель указал свою переменную

```
public void setVariable(SensorState newValue) {
    SensorState oldValue = sensorStateLock;
    sensorStateLock = newValue;
    support.firePropertyChange("sensorStateLock", oldValue, newValue);
}
```

Но событие смены значения переменной не срабатывает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стоит по паттерн Наблюдатель(observer)
[ссылка на wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: Да, спасибо! разобрался. не сразу понял, что "наблюдаемую" переменную нужно изменять через `set()`